# Unable to work around Firefox's AMS.js link restriction

Tags: javascript, firefox, asm.js

I received the error:

```
asm.js link error: As a temporary limitation, modules cannot be linked more than once.
This limitation should be removed in a future release. To work around this, compile a second module (e.g., using the Function constructor).
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this workaround. Does anyone have a working example?

Not my code, but this suffers from the same issue: http://jsperf.com/simplex-noise-comparison-asm
View the issue in the console using FireFox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself. Here's a JSFiddle link for anyone who has the same issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/QLtMB/

```
// Store template as actual function, do not use real pragma to avoid compile
var asmTemplate = function MyAsmModule( stdlib, foreign, heap ) {
   "asm template";

   var HEAP = new stdlib.Uint8Array(heap);
   var _sqrt = stdlib.Math.sqrt;
   var _sin = stdlib.Math.sin;
   var _cos = stdlib.Math.cos;


   function fastSqr( x ) {
      x = +x;
      return +(x*x);
   }

   function fastSqrt( x ) {
      x = +x;
      return +_sqrt( x );
   }

   function fastSin( x ) {
      x = +x;
      return +_sin( x );
   }

   function fastCos( x ) {
      x = +x;
      return +_cos( x );
   }

   function fastTest( x ) {
      x = +x;
      return +fastSqr( 2.17 * (+fastSqrt( 0.75 * +fastSin( x ) + 0.25 * +fastCos( x ) )) );
   }

   return { sqrt: fastSqrt, sin: fastSin, cos: fastCos, test: fastTest };
}

// Generate source string once, replace with real pragma.
asmTemplate = asmTemplate.toString().replace('asm template', 'use asm');

function createASM(buffer) {
    window.asmBufferExport = buffer;
    return Function(asmTemplate + "\nreturn MyAsmModule( Function( 'return this;' )(), null, asmBufferExport.buffer );")();
}

var Asm = createASM(new Uint8Array(4 * 1024));
var Asm2 = createASM(new Uint8Array(4 * 1024));
```

As a bonus, this will round your heap size up to asm.js standards:

```
    var size = <actual size>;
    // Round up to multiple of 4096
    var remainder = size % 4096;
    size = remainder ? size + 4096 - remainder : size;
    // Round up to the nearest power of 2
    size--;
    size |= size >> 1;  // handle  2 bit numbers
    size |= size >> 2;  // handle  4 bit numbers
    size |= size >> 4;  // handle  8 bit numbers
    size |= size >> 8;  // handle 16 bit numbers
    size |= size >> 16; // handle 32 bit numbers
    size++;
```

**Resources**:

- http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#linking-0
- http://pixinsight.com/forum/index.php?topic=6482.0
- http://bits.stephan-brumme.com/roundUpToNextPowerOfTwo.html

Comment: I'd really like a better solution to the buffer global export.

Comment: Unless the heap rounding is performance critical, I suggest Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(x) / Math.LN2))